# Handling permissions to run a bash script

Tags: terminal, applescript, bash, automation, code-signing

I'm sending a bash script as a .command file to a friend. This person is not very tech savvy which is why I'm sending it in the first place, the goal is for the .command file to run through the shell operations for them. However when the attempt to run the script they get the `run.command is damaged and can't be opened. You should move it to the Bin` error. I believe this is a new version of the old unsigned developer prompt as apple is blocking out random code from their systems. Anyway I can have this run without too much complexity?

Edit: I'm open to using applescript if this will alleviate the issue.

Comment: Adding the actual script to your question might help as well...

Comment: @SteveChambers I think the script is irrelevant, it only contains one command, it runs a julia script with some arguments.

Comment: I'm not convinced that all bash scripts copied between computers will result in a 'damaged' error. Nor that bash scripts need to be code-signed. (They don't.) Try zipping it at your end, then sending.

Comment: @benwiggy no i don't believe they all will, I think the issue arises when trying to run the script by opening it from the finder. I did send it as part of a zip file

Comment: I have any number of scripts that I can move between two Macs, without problem.

Comment: @benwiggy how have you been transferring them? Upon research it turns out that files obtained from certain sources e.g. email attachments are tagged as insecure by Finder. This is why it isn't allowing it to open. There are xattr commands to fix the issue, however I believe this is negates the purpose of the script to begin with. https://github.com/processing/processing/issues/4705#issuecomment-257966206

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## AppleScript

Wrap the shell script in a [`do shell script`](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/MacAutomationScriptingGuide/CallCommandLineUtilities.html) AppleScript command:

```
do shell script "say \"hello world\""
```

If your script needs administrator rights, append [`with administrator privileges`](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW40) to the command:

```
do shell script "say \"goodbye moon\"" with administrator privileges
```

Using Script Editor.app in /Applications/Utilities, you can save the AppleScript as a `.applescript` text file that will launch in Script Editor on the host computer.

The end user will need to select the menu item:

- Script (menu) > Run

Alternatively, you can Export as an Application and code sign the resulting application. This assumes you have a code signing certificate available.

[image: Script Editor's Export dialog on macOS]

### Automator

An Automator workflow can also include shell scripts and AppleScripts. Automator can also save as an application, with the Export… menu item also prompting to code sign the result for you.